# SQL Server bulk insert for large data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have 1 million rows of data in a file, I want to insert all the records into SQL Server. While inserting I am doing some comparison with existing data on the server, if the comparison satisfied I will update the existing records in the server or else I will insert the record from the file.

I'm currently doing this by looping from C#, which consume more than 3 hours to complete the work. Can anyone suggest idea to improve the performance?

Thanks,
Xavier.

Comment: BCP.....................

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can we do comparison with existing data with bulk copy program, I'm new to this

Comment: you have to load the data to intermediate table (heap), create the indexes, compare, and finally update the target table. With BCP or any other bulk loading methods, the load should usually take a 10-20 seconds, maximum a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you mean bcp will be used for bulk load alone into staging table. After that I need to comparison with this million data, I'm afraid whether the comparison will take more time

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx - it explains well available methods and sample code

Comment: This is all wrong. You have relational data in a file that you wish to compare to other relational data. Then by golly use a staging table and utilize SQL Server as it was meant to be. Unless you have such stringent resources, staging tables (which are temporary) can allow for batch comparisons....which is pretty much what you are currently doing...only row by row.

Comment: Do Comparison while inserting? Insert it first to another new Database instead, then compare it..

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your database in Full or Simple recovery mode:

   `SELECT recovery_model_desc
   FROM sys.databases
   WHERE name = 'MyDataBase';`
2. If database is `SIMPLE` recovery mode you can create a staging table right there. If it is in `Full` mode then better create Staging table in separate database with `Simple` model.
3. Use any BulkInsert operation/tool (for instance BCP, as already suggested)
4. Insert only those data from your staging table, which do not exist in your target table. (hope you know how to do it)